# Is it possible to compute the probability distribution of a subset of elements which are distributed according to a probability distribution?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, sampling

Let’s say $B$ is a discrete set, $B = \{b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n\}$. If we choose randomly an element of $B$, they are distributed accordingly to $\mathbb{P}( \text{choose }b_i) = p_i$. More formally,
let $\tilde{b}$ be a random variable that picks one $b_i$ at random, then $\mathbb{P}(\tilde{b} = b_i) = p_i$.

Now, let $X$ be the random variable that selects a subset of $B$ of $k$ elements according to the distribution of $\tilde{b}$.
My question is, given a subset containing $k$ elements, $\bar{B} = \{b_{i_1}, \ldots, b_{i_k}\}$, is it possible to explicitely compute the probability distribution of $X$, i.e., $ \mathbb{P}(X = \bar{B}) $?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I'd be highly surprised if this weren't possible. What have you tried so far? My advice would be to test a small case and see what you can find, pattern-wise. The only thing I see as a major stumbling block is order of choice, which *ought* not to matter, but with different probabilities for each element, it might start to matter. (I'm assuming no duplicates, and no replacement.)

Comment: @EricSnyder Thank you! As you say, if we consider ordered vectors of $k$ elements it is quite easy. Here I am interested in unordered subsets, which makes it more difficult. If we consider theprobability of the ordered vector $(b_{i_1}, \ldots, b_{i_k})$, then the probability of picking $b_{i_1}$ is $p_{i_1}$, the prob. of picking $b_{i_2}$, since we are removing $b_{i_1}$, it should be $p_{i_2}/(\sum_{j \neq i_1} p_j)$ and so on. Hence the probability of $(b_{i_1}, \ldots, b_{i_k})$ is $(p_{i_1}p_{i_2} \cdots p_{i_k})/C$, where $C$ depends on $i_1, \ldots, i_k$ and on their sorting.

Comment: the sum of $p_i$ is 1?

Comment: @Exodd, yes the sum of the $p_i$'s is 1

Comment: "Let $X$ be a random variable that selects a subset of $B$ of $k$ elements according to the distribution of $\tilde{b}$": This sentence doesn't make much sense, since $\tilde{b}$ is a single instance and $X$ is now a subset. Is there an IID assumption here? How are you actually selecting the subset?

Comment: @Lorenzo90 Taking a quick look suggests that ordering "matters" but also doesn't matter. Consider objects A, B, and C, with respective probabilities $\frac16, \frac13, \frac12$. If we consider $P(XY)$ as the choice of choosing X and Y in that order, then we get $$P(AB) = \frac1{15}, P(BA) = \frac1{12}, P(AC)=\frac1{10}, P(CA)=\frac16, P(BC)=\frac14, P(CB)= \frac13$$ But those together add to $1$, so you add the orderings together to get the probability for the unordered subsets $(\frac3{20}, \frac4{15}, \frac7{12})$. Finding a *simple* method will take more looking. But *possible*, yes.